# Convert DataFrame to a multi polygon DataFrame, multiple data point - python

Tags: python, dataframe, polygon, geopandas

I have a DataFrame as below, I want to convert data to a multi polygon DataFrame, because I want to plot each multi polygon on a map.

I know how to convert if I have two data point, but with 6 data point, I don't know how to convert it. can anyone help me please.

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(neightrip_counts_.lan0, neightrip_counts_.long0)]
geometry
#neightrip_counts_.lan1, neightrip_counts_.long1,neightrip_counts_.lan2, neightrip_counts_.long2
```

```
    lan0          long0       lan1        long1      lan2         long2
0   59.915667   10.777567   59.916738   10.779916   59.914943   10.773977
1   59.929853   10.711515   59.929435   10.713682   59.927596   10.710033
2   59.939230   10.759170   59.937205   10.760581   59.943750   10.760306
3   59.912520   10.762240   59.911594   10.761774   59.912347   10.763815
4   59.929634   10.732839   59.927140   10.730981   59.931081   10.736003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rename the dataframe `neightrip_counts_` as `df` for brevity. Here is the relevant code that will create a polygon for each row of dataframe.

```
df['geometry'] = [Polygon([(z[0],z[1]), (z[2],z[3]), (z[4],z[5])]) for z in zip(df.long0, df.lan0, df.long1, df.lan1, df.long2, df.lan2)]
gpdf = df.set_geometry("geometry", drop=True)
gpdf.plot()
```

[image: polyplot]

By the way, you must be careful about the sequence of (long, lat).

```
start_coords = [ gdf.centroid[0].x, gdf.centroid[0].y] # is wrong
```

Use this in stead.

```
start_coords = [ gdf.centroid[0].y, gdf.centroid[0].x]
```

**Edit**

For the benefits of the readers, here is the complete runnable code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from io import StringIO

from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
import numpy as np
import folium

data1 = """index    lan0          long0       lan1        long1      lan2         long2
0   59.915667   10.777567   59.916738   10.779916   59.914943   10.773977
1   59.929853   10.711515   59.929435   10.713682   59.927596   10.710033
2   59.939230   10.759170   59.937205   10.760581   59.943750   10.760306
3   59.912520   10.762240   59.911594   10.761774   59.912347   10.763815
4   59.929634   10.732839   59.927140   10.730981   59.931081   10.736003"""

# read/parse data into dataframe
df0 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep='\s+', index_col='index')
# create `geometry` column
df0['geometry'] = [Polygon([(xy[0],xy[1]), (xy[2],xy[3]), (xy[4],xy[5])]) \
                   for xy in zip(df0.long0, df0.lan0, df0.long1, df0.lan1, df0.long2, df0.lan2)]

# set geometry
gpdf = df0.set_geometry("geometry", drop=True)

# do check plot. (uncomment next line)
#gpdf.plot()

# make geojson
center_pt = gpdf.centroid[0].y, gpdf.centroid[0].x
gdf_json = gpdf.to_json()

# plot the geojson on the folium webmap
webmap = folium.Map(location = center_pt, zoom_start = 13, min_zoom = 3)
folium.GeoJson(gdf_json, name='data_layer_1').add_to(webmap)

# this opens the webmap
webmap
```

Output screen capture (of interactive webmap):

[image: webmap]

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Seems I swapped my coordinates around, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming the 'lan' is latitude.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium

# ....

def addpolygeom(row):
    row_array = np.array(row)
    # split dataframe row to a list of tuples (lat, lon)
    coords = [tuple(i)[::-1] for i in np.split(row_array, range(2, row_array.shape[0], 2))]
    polygon = Polygon(coords)
    return polygon

# Convert points to shapely geometry
neightrip_counts_['geometry'] = neightrip_counts_.apply(lambda x: addpolygeom(x), axis=1)

# Create a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(neightrip_counts_, geometry='geometry')

start_coords = [ gdf.centroid[0].y, gdf.centroid[0].x]
gdf_json = gdf.to_json()

map = folium.Map(start_coords, zoom_start=4)
folium.GeoJson(gdf_json, name='mypolygons').add_to(map)
```